# GWT super dev more "ignored get request"

Tags: servlets, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have a servlet in my GWT project that simply sends a "hello world" on get. Unfortunately in super dev mode in GWT I see no "Hello world" in my browser and see this in the GWT logs...

> [WARN] ignored get request: /slimupdates/updates

Any idea if there is some odd behaviour with super dev mode ignoring requests?

Comment: Look at this thread [Fixes Super Dev Mode to work for a GWT app that uses the PrecompileLinker (issue1783803)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/eCjSPOmoUAI). Its just a WARNING.

Answer (score 3):

That message is emitted by the SuperDevMode web server when it receives a request it doesn't know how to handle. That means your "hello world" sends the request not to your server but to the SuperDevMode server.

That means that either you have a problem in the way the path to the servlet is specified, or you didn't load your "hello world" page from your server (where the servlet lives) but from the SuperDevMode server.

(in case you didn't know: yes, SuperDevMode means running 2 servers: your server with your server-side code –could be the DevMode embedded server– and the SuperDevMode)